# If we know how one variable depends on another, can we "plug" this into the total derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose we have a function $f(x,y)$.

The total derivative is $f_1(x,y)dx+f_2(x,y)dy$.

Now suppose that we know the explicit relationship between x and y. For example, suppose we know $y=h(x)$.

Then can we just write the total derivative as $f_1(x,y)dx+f_2(x,y)*h'(x)dx$?

(which is just the "partial" derivative of $f(x,h(x))$ w.r.t $x$. (I put partial in quotes because i guess in this second formulation $f$ is really just a function of one variable).

If the above is true, then what do we use the total derivative for? Because for any application wouldn't we have an explicit dependency between $x$ and $y$? (and hence just be able to simplify to the latter case)

Comment: If you're looking for an application of this exact thing, where we can't just "simplify away" $y$, consider the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the torus:

$$
\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - R\right)^2 + z^2 = r^2
$$

I think you'll find it's difficult to produce a global, explicit, functional relationship between the variables.

More generally, if you can parameterize an equation in terms of a single variable, then yes, I think you can express the total derivative in terms of that one variable. Is it always possible achieve a one-parameter restatement of a function? No, I don't believe it is in a useful sense.

You give an example of when it would be possible (assuming all the functions are sufficiently differentiable), but here is how I would have thought about that particular example:

If you expressed $y = h(x)$, you would produce a new function:

$$
g(x) = f(x, h(x))
$$

and the total derivative of this function would be $Dg_{x_0}(dx) = g'(x_0)dx$.

My earlier point is that it is not always possible to find a globally-defined function $g(t) = f(x_1(t), \dots, x_n(t))$, and even when it is possible, it is not always convenient.